# Grouping of search auto complete suggestions for Solr

Tags: solr, solrnet, solr4

I am working on Solr 4.9 with auto complete using suggester component.

But I'm clueless how to get grouping of search auto complete suggestions. I have already gone through this great article http://www.cominvent.com/2012/01/25/super-flexible-autocomplete-with-solr/ however, it doesn't explain how to achieve this.

Can anyone give us any hint that would help us to proceed.

Answer (score 1):

The example you've referenced doesn't use the new Suggester component, as that was added after it was written. The post does use NGrams to generate word and token parts, which is then used to generate hits (and weight them differently) when searching (Suggester is mainly tuned for "Did you mean?" information, but can be used for auto complete as well). Jan [has added the complete example on github](https://github.com/cominvent/autocomplete), so you cna drill down into anything you need to see how it works.

Depending on your matching needs, a prefix search (q=field:token*) would probably be the easiest way to solve it. A more flexible option might be to use ngrams, but it all depends on your needs.

Regardless of which method you choose you can then apply [Result Grouping](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Result+Grouping) to get x amount of hits for each type in your index.